symplectic real 2-form on $\mathbb{CP}^n$
I'd like to prove that $\mathbb{CP}^n$ admits a symplectic 2-form (when regarded as a real manifold of dimension $2n$). The hint I was given was to consider the form $x^1 \wedge y^1 + \cdots + x^{n+1} \wedge y^{n+1}$ on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ (with $z = x +iy$) and then restrict this form to $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$. This should give me the desired form on the projective space. I'm having trouble understanding what exactly this means. I assumed it meant that this form is invariant under the action of $\mathbb{S}^1$ on $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1}$, and I guess this means that I can sort of push it down to $\mathbb{CP}^n$, so my question is the following: how do I show that the form I wrote is $\mathbb{S}^1$-invariant? Does this actually imply that I can push it down to the projective plane? If so, how?

This is called the Fubini-Study form. It is also a special case of "symplectic reduction."

You’re right. You have to push the form down. This of course doesn’t work in general. I don't fully understand your notation. Here is an outline of a proof using different notation.
$\newcommand\C{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand\CP{\C P}$The differential of the projection  map $\pi: S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \CP^n$ is, for each $\hat u \in S^{2n+1}$, a surjective linear map
$$
\pi_*: T_{\hat u}S^{2n+1} \rightarrow T_{u}\CP^n,
$$
where $u = \pi(\hat{u})$.
Let $\hat\omega$ be the $2$-form on $S^{2n+1}$ that you're considering. The desired symplectic form on $\CP^n$ at each $u \in \CP^n$ is the real $2$-tensor
$$
\omega: T_u\CP^n \times T_u\CP^n \rightarrow \C,
$$
where for each $v_1, v_2 \in T_u\CP^n$,
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
\omega(v_1,v_2) = \hat\omega(\hat{v}_1,\hat{v}_2),
\end{equation}
and $\hat v_1,\hat v_2 \in T_{\hat u}S^{2n+1}$ satisfy
$$
\pi_*\hat{v_1} = v_1\text{ and }\pi_*\hat{v}_2 = v_2.
$$
Since $\hat{u}, \hat{v}_1, \hat{v}_2$ are not uniquely determined by $u, v_1, v_2$ and  the assumptions above, proving that this is a logically consistent definition of $\omega$ requires showing that the right side of (*) does not depend on the choice of the $\hat{u}, \hat{v}_1, \hat{v}_2$ are used.
It's worth noting that the above argument works if you replace each $S^{2n+1}$ by $\C^{n+1}\backslash\{0\}$. The calculations are simpler if you do this.
You probably need to translate what I wrote above into your own notation.

If I'm not wrong, we have that $T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1} = Span(z) \oplus z^ {\perp}$ and $\pi$ sends the latter term isomorphically to $T_{[z]}\mathbb{CP}^n$. Hence two vectors $v_1, v_2 \in T_z\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ are sent to the same tangent vector iff they differ by a multiple of $z$. This means that I should be checking that, given $w_1, w_2$ and $v_1, v_2$ with $w_1 = v_1 + c_1z$ and $w_2 = v_2 + c_2z$, then $\hat{\omega}(w_1,w_2) = \hat{\omega}(v_1,v_2)$. Once I've done this, $\omega$ is well-defined on each point of the projective space. Is this outline correct?

That looks correct.

Was your hint perhaps to consider the $2$-form $\omega=dx^1\wedge dy^1+dx^2\wedge dy^2 + \dots + dx^{n+1}\wedge dy^{n+1}$ on $\Bbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}$? Writing $z^j=x^j+iy^j$, note that $dz^j\wedge d\bar z^j = dz^j\wedge d\overline{z^j} = -2idx^j\wedge dy^j$, and so $$\omega = \frac i2\left(dz^1\wedge d\bar z^1 + \dots + dz^{n+1}\wedge d\bar z^{n+1}\right).$$
Now you can easily pullback $\omega$ under the map $\psi_\theta\colon\Bbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}\to\Bbb C^{n+1}-\{0\}$ given by $\psi_\theta(z)=e^{i\theta}z$ and check that $\psi_\theta^*\omega = \omega$.
